# What does 'value initializing' something mean?

Tags: c++, default-value, value-initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat)

If I have a class for example:

```
class Info
{
   int x;
   int y;
};
```

which I used to created an object,

```
Info *p = new Info();
```

Does the brackets beside Info mean i'm value initializing it? How does it different from this, `Info *p = new Info;` ?

I know there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402) which differentiate between different meanings in new and old C++ language but I want to know the semantic difference between default and value initialization e.g. Does value initialization means initializing something to zero?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/), [Difference between default-initialize and value-initialize in C++03?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084831/).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A declared variable can be **Zero Initialized**, **Value Initialized** or **Default Initialized**.

In your example:

```
Info *p = new Info();    <------- Value Initialization
Info *p = new Info;      <------- Default Initialization
```

The C++03 Standard 8.5/5 aptly defines each:

To **zero-initialize** an object of type T means:

— if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;
— if T is a non-union class type, each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject
  is zero-initialized;
— if T is a union type, the object’s first named data member is zero-initialized;
— if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
— if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

To **default-initialize** an object of type T means:
— if T is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the 
  initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
— if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
— otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
— if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default 
  constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible 
  default constructor);
— if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static 
  data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
— if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
— otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

Comment: In my case, class `Info` is POD class type. Does it mean default initialization will be zero initialization?

Comment: @user1086635: Yes. It is clearly mentioned in the second paragraph of the Standard Quote above.

Comment: This answer is invalid for anything later than C++03. See the "Possible Duplicate" for an updated answer, as well as [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

Comment: Clarification on default initialization: according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) the last bullet should be "otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values." This is what allows default initialized scalars to have any value rather than be zero initialized.

Comment: According to the definition of 'default-initialize' explained above:  `int i;` Here `i` should be initialized to zero., but at several other places on the internet I read that it's value in this case remains indeterminate. Which one is true !  Or please point out my mistake in understanding.