# Value initialization on explicit constructor call in C++?

Tags: c++, class, default-constructor, value-initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat)

There are multiple places where people have said that an explicit call to the class constructor results in value initialization [when no used-defined constructors exist] and that this is not done by the default constructor [which is a do-nothing constructor] but is something completely different.

What happens actually if no constructor is called OR What is value initialization in this case ?

Comment: There is always the standard that documents this behaviour, but i guess that wasn't what you meant, or was it?

Comment: *is there documentation that supports/mentions/explains this behaviour?* Yes, it is called *The Standard*

Comment: Check this: [What does 'value initializing' something mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860780/what-does-value-initializing-something-mean)

Comment: That was fast o.O
Thanks for pointing that out @Als. Didnt find it while searching.

Comment: Am i missing something ?


As per your answer, 

eg. class A { int i; };


A x = A(); -> Value initialization so i=0. Fine.


A x -> Default initialization, this is POD class type, hence it should also be zero initialized ??

Comment: @Als, could you please explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firstly, what happens actually if no constructor is called

A constructor for a class-type is always called when an object is constructed, be it user-defined or compiler-generated. The object is initialized, but the members can remain un-initialized. This makes the second part of the question obsolete.

> Second, is there documentation that supports/mentions/explains this behaviour ?

The all-mighty standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is only true for **aggregates**: Consider this:

```
struct Holder
{
   Aggregate a;
   NonAggr   n;

   Holder(int, char) : a(), n() { }
   Holder(char, int) { }
};

Holder h1(1, 'a');
Holder h2('b', 2);
```

Suppose `Aggregate` is an aggregate type. Now `h1.a` is value-initialized, which value-initializes each member, while `h2.a` is default-initialized, which default-initializes each member. The same holds for the `n` member, but if `NonAggr` is a non-aggregate class type, its default constructor will always be called.