# How to make sure that recently created area points to NULL?

Tags: c++

How can I make sure that, for each allocated new space on heap area, the recently created element of vector of pointers points to NULL ?

```
 Ex:
   vector < Sometype* >

   vector ----------------------
          |  |  |  | ...       |
          ----------------------

   new element is pushed back but no available area so double space

   index                         x  x+1            y
   vector -------------------------------------------
          |  |  |  | ...       |   |   | ...        |
          -------------------------------------------

                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                 recently created

         x, x+1, ... y all points to the NULL
```

I want each space on recently created part point to NULL ?

Comment: You can't (legally) access the part you're talking about, so why does it matter what stuff lies in there?

Comment: Please can we have that question in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This new space is part of the capacity of the vector, but not part of the size. You shouldn't need to care what values it contains, since you're not allowed to access it anyway. Other than the one value you pushed back, the extra space is not "elements of the vector", it's just unused space.

As far as the standard is concerned, the implementation could use it to store something meaningful, if it wanted. For example, an implementation could legally store some eye-catcher value in the unused memory, which conflicts with your desire for the unused memory to contain null pointers.

You could write code like this:

```
v.push_back(some_value);
if (v.capacity() > v.size()) {
    size_t oldsize = v.size();
    v.resize(v.capacity(), NULL);
    v.resize(oldsize);
}
```

There's no guarantee this will actually leave the memory set to 0 once you resize back down again, but it probably will. So it might be good enough for debugging. If the purpose you have in mind is not debugging, please say what it is, because if not debugging then either your purpose is illegitimate or else one of us has misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, one straightforward solution is to call `resize()` yourself passing `NULL` [as second argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to be used as default value for newly created items:

```
if (v.size() == v.capacity()) //vector is full
{
    //compute the new size
    size_t newSize = 2 * v.size();

    //second argument is the default value for newly added items
    v.resize(newSize, NULL); 
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is incorrect/misleading. Even if you do not provide 2nd argument, std::vector will zero-initialize new elements regardless. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481693/271376).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need it to be NULL unless it's been constructed? If you create a vector of 10 objects, say, and then push an extra, 11th item onto the vector then the vector may *reserve* enough space for another 10 items but you cannot use those items unless you either push items onto the vector increasing it's size, or you call `resize`.

`size` is not the same as `capacity`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need that? `vector` does not allow you to access these elements anyway. The expanding of it's capacity is implementation detail of vector and values of elements at the allocated space are not relevant. These elements will get overwritten once you `push_back` something there, or `resize` the vector with the given value.

There is an important difference between `capacity` and `size` of a vector.

Answer (score 0):

When you push new elements into vector and there is no room, although std::vector allocates extra memory for new elements (similar to reserve() call), it does not create them (does not call constructors). See [placement "new"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) to understand how this could work. There's no real way to enforce certain value for new elements, because there are no new elements - only raw memory block allocated for future elements. By using std::vector::at instead of operator[] you can ensure that you're accessing elements within valid range.

If you resize vector yourself by calling [std::vector::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/), then simply provide default value for new elements in 2nd parameters. However, there's a catch. When you resize std::vector yourself and do not provide value for 2nd argument of std::vector::resize, std::vector will value-initialize new elements if value stored in std::vector has constructor and zero-initialize them otherwise. Which means, that if you do `std::vector<int*> v; v.resize(200);`, all new elements of v will be initialized to zero. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481693/271376) answer for details.