# Why default constructor of private member is not called?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constructor, member

I have reduced my problem to the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class B
{
public:
    B(){
        cout<<"Default ctor of B"<<endl;
    };
};

class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        cout<<"Default ctor of C"<<endl;
    }
    void sayHello()
    {
        cout<<"Say hello"<<endl;
    }
};
class A: public B
{
public:
    void fun()
    {
        c.sayHello();
    }
private:
    C c;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A* a=new A();
    a->fun();
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

When I create object of A, I can see that default constructor of C is not called, but when I invoke A::fun() it invokes C::sayHello() properly. How is that possible? I crosscompile it under specific toolchain, but still how is it possible to allocate object memory and not invoke it's default ctor's body? That seems to be obvious compiler bug, isn't it?

When I compiled the above code with GCC on Fedora, it all worked as expected...

EDIT:
Compiler is GCC-4.2 tailored for Broadcom chipset. Problem exists on embedded system, when code is executed. What solves it, is adding default empty constructor to A:

```
A(){}
```

even without explicitly calling C member's default constructor on it's initialization list.

Comment: which gcc version? sounds like buggy compiler. works at 4.8

Comment: Works under MSVC.  Is there possibly some quirk of `cout` in play here...?

Comment: Feels more like a cut/paste error. The code posted here is not identical to the code being used by the OP. This code should work as described and a compiler bug that sever would have been reported long ago.

Comment: Are you going to tell us which toolchain and under which conditions you observe this behaviour?

Comment: It is not a copy/paste error. The compiler is gcc-4.2 tailored for one of Broadcom chipsets.

Comment: You should put that information in the question.

Comment: @user1158692 - this has nothing to do with cout, I used it here for presentation purposes. In the original code I observe the problem by seeing in sayHello()'s respective method that some of the class B's members are not initialized in a way they should be if the ctor would had been invoked.

Comment: @flyjohny Fair enough on `cout`.  What happens if you put a breakpoint in `C`s constructor?

Comment: I can't, it is executed on embedded system. But that breakpoint would be missed probably, because no code in default constructor seems to be executed. Only memory allocation that allows method's invokation. Please find the remarks I added to my original question.

Comment: @flyjohny: Try setting some global variable in the CTOR of C, drop the cout thing...

Comment: @flyjohny: I advise examining the generated assembly for `A::A()`.

Comment: @flyjohny: what happens if you do `int main() { A a; a.fun(); return 0; }` ? I wonder if the `new` participates to the issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

@juanchopanza is correct that calling the ctor of C lazily is not standards-compliant behavior for the compiler. "An object is not considered constructed until its constructor has completed." (Stroustrup, *The C++ Programming Language*, 3rd Ed, p. 366).

However, there may be another subtlety at play here, around the difference between default constructors and so-called value-initialization. See these two previous StackOverflow answers:

- [Does the default constructor initialize built-in types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types)
- [Difference between default-initialize and value-initialize in C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084831/difference-between-default-initialize-and-value-initialize-in-c03)

Depending on whether your compiler considers C to be a POD type, and whether it's conforming to the C++98 or C++03 standard, it may be doing value initialization instead of the default ctor. The fact that adding a user-declared default ctor to A changes the behavior is a clue that this issue is in play.

Comment: `C` can't be a POD if it has a user-defined constructor. It's just a compiler bug.

Comment: @Daniel Hardman - this is interesting. C is not POD, but this suggestion about value initialization seems to apply somehow here. However, as previously mentioned, it must be a compiler bug. But I give you a vote for interesting perspective.